# iOS Enterprise App distribution OTA

Tags: ios, enterprise, iphone-developer-program, over-the-air

I'm trying to create OTA for my enterprise app. I have created all pre-requisite for the same including signing certificate, provisioning profile.  When I use apples standard hyperlink link nothing happens on the device, just blank screen. I've uploaded IPA and manifest file to https storage and pointed the hyperlink to manifest location.

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/manifest.plist">Install App</a>
```

Am I missing something here?

Here is my plist.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://example.com/sampleApp.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://example.com/logo%2057%20X%2057.png</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://example.com/logo%20512%20X%20512.png</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.sampleApp</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>1.0</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>sampleApp</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022642/ios-app-enterprise-distribution-deployment-missing-app-plist

Comment: Linking to the plist file with http scheme directly is just ok, tested in webview and safari.

Comment: @Itachi could you elaborate the details.

Comment: @Krunal I did all the steps in the other SO answer but still not working. When I try direct link as "itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://example.com/manifest.plist" in browser, it's ask to open iTune and nothing happens after that.

Comment: @Pandurang Yachwad There is no role of iTune for Enterprise app distribution. why does it ask you for iTune.

Comment: @Krunal itms-Services prompts the iTunes, even though it doesn’t have any role in enterprise app distribution. BTW, what would be the link or url to open the manifest.plist?

Comment: @Krunal I've updated my question with my .plist.

Comment: `<a href="https://example.com/manifest.plist">Install App</a>`, try it. The webview and safari will recognize the app production and download the plist file as an index file.

Comment: @Itachi When I try above link directly, I'm getting content of plist file in the safari browser instead of getting the app install.

Comment: @Krunal what would be url to hit the plist file?

Comment: Make sure the MIME type from your web server is `text/xml` for the plist file, or the browser will regard it as plain text.

Comment: @Itachi yes ipa and plist are both in expected MIME format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix the issue. I see issue was with not having correct signing certificate. For anyone who want to distribute the app in-house without MDM they can follow steps in below blog post. 
https://medium.com/apps-studio/distributing-enterprise-ios-app-in-house-without-mdm-3ed015009893