# Cannot install ad-hoc IPA using the Xcode Automatically Manage Signing

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I thought this was a thing in the past when Xcode introduce automatically manage signing in Xcode 8. Suddenly, signing in becomes so easy and hassle free, just need to do the critical part of creating the team and etc.

But today when I tried to export one of my old project using Ad-hoc, I got the familiar popup "(This application) could not be download at this time". I have use the recommended setup, which is use the automatically manage signing + using "iOS developer" as code signing identity. I even tried to use manual signing mode and supply all the provision and certificate myself, but still no luck. I even tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21537619/3003927) to install the app via device/organizer and then look into the console/device logs. But turns out the IPA can be installed successfully without issue. So I don't know why there's this issue.

Btw, recently, I've just duplicated the target, and rename copied target to a different bundle ID. But the one that has problem is the old original one.

Some notes:

- I have made sure that the manifest.plist points to the correct url, using https, and the filename has the correct case. I also made sure that the app's bundle ID match with the one I'm going to install.
- Both on automatically manage signing and manual signing, I have also made sure that the device test I'm using on is already registered on the developer central, and is included with the provisioning.
- On keychain, I have *one* iPhone Distribution certificate of my team. But I cannot see iPhone Developer certificate of my team. I do see iPhone Developer certificate of my own account though. I don't know if this matters or not.
- I can see that I have both eligible and ineligible provisioning with same name that Xcode automatically generate for the target. I saw this when I unchecked the automatically manage signing and choose the provisioning profile from the dropdown. I don't know if this matters or not.
- On subsequent attempts, I have removed all the provisioning and let Xcode create anew. Still does not work. Use manual signing and download the new adhoc provisioning, still does not work.
- I just noticed that whenever I use manual signing and select method for export into ad-hoc, the provisioning profile used on the "Summary:" screen is using the one Xcode created automatically, not the one I selected from the Xcode target general settings. I cannot change it into my selection. Is that a problem?

Can anybody help what the cause is? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is only a problem of cache. After I restart the phone, I can install it properly, using any method, even the automatically manage signing ones.